# Removing and re-using a Shimano Tourney deraileur hanger - vintage road bike

Tags: shimano, derailleur-rear, vintage, tourney

I've acquired a Shimano 600 derailleur (see last photo) that's going to replace a Shimano Tourney derailleur (photos 1-3).

I don't have the hanger for the Shimano 600 so I was thinking of removing Tourney's hanger and re-using it. Any ideas if this will work? If so, how do you remove it?

I've removed the rubber cap (see photos 1 and 2) but I'm not sure how to proceed. If this is going to be difficult or if the hanger isn't compatible, are there some modern hangers that would do the trick, as they would be easier to find?

Thanks!

[image: Rubber cap]

[image: Removed rubber cap]

[image: Back of hanger]

[image: New deraileur]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The claw adapter piece of the Tourney you have isn't designed to be removable in any way. All you need is one of these, called a claw adapter:

[image]

Answer (score 9):

Your plan won't work sorry.   I did exactly the same, removing a claw adapter from a slogged-out tourney derailleur.

It was a press-fit, not a threadded fit, and the hole is too big to take the thread required.  So I gained nothing but experience, and had to buy the claw adapter in Nathan's answer anyway.

On the positive side, the right part is cheap because its pressed steel and not unique like all the modern hangers.  Any LBS should have them for $cheap, or buy some from Uncle Ali.